# to tell the reputation of the publisher that publishes books

Tags: publications

It's easier to tell the reputation of a journal because we publish journal papers most of the time.How to tell the reputation of the publisher that publishes books? Some publishers reach out to published papers to be published again by them as book chapters in their books. Is this normal?

Comment: what is normal, in your opinion?

Comment: *"Some publishers reach out to published papers to be published again by them as book chapters in their books. Is this normal?"* --- No. This is usually a predatory style of publishing. Avoid.

Comment: @EarlGrey normal in my view is sth acceptable in academia, then i'll do it

Comment: @Dilworth thanks for the tip but this publisher says it's ok to do so. I can't tell who's right

Comment: @feynman, the publisher which is probably predatory would clearly say it's okay to do so, because of their predatory nature.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is as follows:

- Go to your preferred library;
- look for available titles from that publisher;
- pick one book dealing with a topic you a have some familiarity;
- judge it for yourself.

Please note: "go to your preferred library" can be the digital version, i.e. checking out ebooks or writing an email to your library asking if they can provide you books from that publisher on a certain topic.

Comment: they could say we can't view full texts of their books without paying or subscribing. All I can see are their titles of chapters.

Comment: @feynman It is customary for libraries to **buy** books, so there is nothing special.
Book publisher are for profit companies, or they have at least to cover their expenses and employees, so they cannot afford to do things for free.
If a publisher makes it really hard for people to read their books, I would say "the publisher do not really want people to read their books". Fair enough, there is a market for everyone, one of the biggest thing of capitalism is great at separating fools from their money, I personally prefer to make people less fool than they are. Reading books help, so...

Comment: @feynman: if your university library is decent, and has not paid for access to any of this publisher's books, that is a really bad sign.

Comment: +1 for go to the library. And, if you're lucky you can also ask the librarian for help!

Answer (score 5):

To complement EarlGrey's excellent answer, the answer is in the question itself:
to *"tell the reputation of the publisher"* observe if it *"reaches out to published papers to be published again by them as book chapters in their books*" --- if the answer is "yes", then it's normally of low reputation.