# Offers to include my published paper in an open access book?

Tags: publications, books, open-access

I published a paper, and I've been receiving offers from various publishers to include the paper in open access books. What should I do please?

Comment: You should ignore them

Comment: Once you publish a paper with your name on it, you are essentially guaranteed to get these emails, at least one a week. I just counted and there are 14 in my weekly spam folder. These are not genuine, they are trying to get you to pay to get something already published republished in their fake journals. Aside from the copyright infringement this may cause, you will win nothing either economical or academically.

Comment: There's something very wrong with your question. Where did you publish your paper?

If you published it subscription then you don't hold the copyright, and you don't get to publish your paper in the open access book.

If you published it open access, then it's already open access. You could let them include it in the book, but there'd be absolutely no reason to make an open access paper "even more" open access. Hence, VTC for lacking details.

Comment: I'm glad this question was asked. Although experienced researchers are familiar with these predatory requests, it is not obvious starting out that these should be ignored. In the long run, quality of publication is MUCH more important than quantity. Congrats on your recent publication Hela, and wishing you a happy career with many more!

Comment: Have you heard of the publisher which is supposed to be publishing the book, or every used one of their books?  No, so delete it, its spam.

Answer (score 20):

Be very careful about this. Many such emails are automated spam: people automatically scrape recently published papers and automatically generate such "invitation" emails. This mainly tries to get you to pay high "Article Processing Charges". Your paper may well end up in some PDF collection with completely unrelated stuff, which will not serve your academic career at all. (If the publication actually happens at all.)

I would very much recommend you only even reply to this if the email comes from someone you know, or whose name you recognize. If someone in the field is putting together a collection, that might be interesting. But even then you should try reaching out to that person *using a different means of contact than given in the email* (because any "contact information" in that email may well be fake), so find their institutional email address and ask them on that whether they are actually involved with this effort.

If this is just a canned spam email from some "publisher" you do not know, then just delete it.

Comment: *some "publisher" you do not know* 100% agree: if you think you are ignorant, you may always try to check the publisher quality of previous works (see question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202331/to-tell-the-reputation-of-the-publisher-that-publishes-books/202496#202496 )